# Add Path to OSX to El Capitan

Tags: bash, path

I am trying to learn UNIX. 
I am using a book called “Wicked Cool Shell Scripts”.

I am told that `.bash_profile` contains my login for bash and that I can add paths to it so that commands I enter in Terminal will find the scripts I am writing.

The contents of my current bash_profile is:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

When I type `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I would like to add a path so that - as the book suggests - I can write scripts and refer to them directly from the command line, instead of having to constantly navigate to that directory to run them.

I have a file with a shebang. It runs fine when I type its name and am in the same directory. I have moved that file to the folder scripts, which is located under `crg/Users/` (ie: `Users/crg/scripts`)
According to this book, I can now alter my `$PATH` to include that directory, so that when I type that filename, the program will run.

I cannot do this successfully. 
I don’t know why. 
After *every* edit, I quit terminal and reopen it, to ensure it is using the newly edited bash_profile.

As per the books instructions on page 5, I have tried entering this in my bash_profile:

```
export PATH=”/Users/crg/scripts/:$PATH”
```

I save my bash_profile, quit Terminal, reopen it and type `echo $Path`

This is the result:

```
”/Users/crg/scripts/:??
```

This is not right. In fact, it's wildly wrong. And it does not allow me to run scripts from the folder indicated. It also seems to completely overwrite whatever was in the bash_profile before this, so I cannot - after doing this 'simple edit' suggested by a 'professional' - run a `php -version` command from the Terminal.

I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening.

1. Why is there a quotation mark at the beginning of this line (but not at the end)?
2. What's with the colon and the 2 question marks at the end of this line?
3. How do I add/append a path to my bash_profile?

More questions: 
When I try and solve this on my own using “the Internet”, I discover many interesting versions of this ‘simple’ process: Here’s one suggested by a ‘professional’:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/program/inside/package"
```

This is very different from what the book says...

Here’s another version of ‘how to do it’ by ‘a professional’:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin/modemZapp
```

Notice that this one doesn’t even have quotes. In both, the `PATH` variable comes before the actual path.

Why are there so many 'versions' of how to perform this simple task?

Can someone please tell me how to add a path to my `.bash_profile`?

UPDATE: I have followed the [advice here](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg), (add it to `etc/paths`) but this **does not work** either. 
I get the  exact same thing when I type `echo $PATH` in a new Terminal:

```
/usr/local/opt/php@7.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/fhb/scripts:/opt/X11/bin
```

I can't help but note a comment on that last page: "I have been through at least a dozen different methods for adding directories to `$PATH`. Why are there so many and why do so few of them work?"

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question if you look closely your quotes are `”` instead of `"`. I'm guessing you edited either your bash_profile or this post in a rich text editor instead of a plain text one. I would recommend notepad for Windows or nano for *nix if you are writing code. To fix this issue, replace the ” with ".

To answer your second question, bash is quite forgiving and will allow you to set a string variable in multiple different ways, even without quotes. However you can run into issues when a string contains whitespace, for example: `/Users/lilHenry/my scripts`.

The `"${PATH}"` syntax is just another way to declare a string. It has the benefit that it allows you to interpolate variables into a string like so:

`prefix="foo"
echo "${prefix}bar"`

This will output `foobar`, whereas `echo "$prefixbar"` will not output anything as the variable prefixbar has not been set. I would suggest sticking with the `export PATH="/Users/me/bin:$PATH"` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you.
I am timid about using nano, but the second I opened up .bash_profile in it, I realized the error in using a very old version of TextWrangler.
Here's a small portion of what was in there...
...
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

so, using that as my example, I wrote this...

# Setting a PATH for myScripts
PATH="Users/crg/scripts:${PATH}"
export PATH

Note though, that the formatting is significantly different; parentheses wrap, for example. A little disconcerting.
Thanks *very* much again!

Comment: I'm glad that helped.